# how to create folder on server from code in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

Is there any way to show user popup to give the name to create folder

And with that if he does not want to create folder then he should be shown the list of folders to which he want to save the file

Is it proper way that I create a popup with javascript with the list of folders on my server and put a textbox and button to save the new and in code we will create directory in code passed with textbox?

Comment: Are you looking for `SaveFileDialog`?

Comment: yes.to save the new directory and to show the existing directories

Comment: It is only possible in **Windows Forms** application, you cannot do this in asp.net.

Comment: on a web app you would normally not ask where to save the files, folders are more for a desktop application, on a web app they don't make much sense, you could however let the users apply some type of tags or other metadata

Comment: that is true, but i am doing file uploading and user wants store perticular file in perticular folder.so is that possible some how? or any other alternate way to fullfill this?

Comment: you could call them "folders" if you want (from the user perspective), but instead of actually creating the folders and managing them (duplicated, race conditions, etc) you could just store those in some database

Comment: your suggestion is valid enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned by commenting that **Functionality like `SaveFileDialog` is only possible in Windows Forms application, you cannot do this in asp.net**

The alternatives in asp.net are difficult however as an alternate there is a third party editor available on the web called [CKEditor 3.x Developer's Guide](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide).

You can use [File Browser (Uploader)](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/File_Browser_%28Uploader%29) for the purpose you want to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

```
string pathToCreate = "~/UserFolders/" + TextBox1.Text;
if(Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(pathToCreate))
{
   //In here, start looping and modify the path to create to add a number
   //until you get the value needed
}

//Now you know it is ok, create it
Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(pathToCreate));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
                        string targetPath = Server.MapPath("FolderName"); //with complete path
                        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
                        {
                            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);                               
                            fileToUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(targetPath + ImageFileName);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            fileToUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(targetPath + ImageFileName);
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

to create folder :

```
 System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);//newpath is your folder creating path
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Example given in [How to Create a Folder or File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as2f1fez.aspx) You can create a folder, but in asp.net you can not Use open file dialog or save file dialog functionalities, this will work only in C# Windows forms application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing web applications (I can see you have tagged your question as asp.net), you do not need to worry about the pop up window. You just send the file through the Response and the download window will be shown by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Web applications and the HTTP protocol do not support direct manipulation of the server-side file system. In fact, that would be a dangerous idea.

It sounds like you have a base folder somewhere on the web server where you want users to be able to upload files, with some user control over subfolders and location of the uploaded file. I would suggest dong this by presenting the file system in a tree view or a list of links (where the links let you navigate up/down the folder tree). Combine this with a file input and you've got yourself a solution. HOWEVER, be very careful to control and cleanse the specified file name for the uploaded file. There are many combinations (such as utilizing "..") that can allow the user to hack into unwanted file locations on your server.